# Open new asp.net page without reload

Tags: asp.net, postback

how to make on asp.net such a transition between pages as there http://templates-preview.com/HTML5/300111646/index.html (new page slide from right without reload)

Comment: It is called single page application see here with knockout you can use many other librareis/frameworks e.g. angularjs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I do not need a SPA, I need to open a new page by clicking on the link, but without a reload. Look at the example I cited above

Comment: They have written this request url script : http://templates-preview.com/HTML5/300111646/js/request_url.js

Comment: you can jquery $.load() function to load new html but page url will be same